# How to stop pinned SliverAppBar from covering floating SliverPersistentHeader

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm learning Flutter and I am currently trying to make a home page with a cool scrolling effect. I'm trying to implement a CustomScrollView with 3 elements: a SliverAppBar, a horizontal scrolling list and a SliverList. The first two were easy enough and after some struggling I managed to implement the horizontal scrolling list by using a SliverPersistentHeader.

However, I ran into an issue. I want the SliverAppBar to be pinned and the SliverPersistentHeader containing the horizontal scrolling list to be floating. Everything works fine, except the floating element **gets covered** by the pinned one when scrolling back up after scrolling down. I basically want the floating element to "know" there is another element above it and offset itself when scrolling up.

You can see the issue here, alongside my code:
https://dartpad.dev/32d3f2a890d4a676decb014744fcc9ba

**Make sure you click and drag to scroll in order to see the issue!**

How can I fix this? Is there anything I am missing that causes this issue?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you want the SliverPersistentHeader to become visible immediately scroll to the top is initiated?

Comment: Yes. This way, if the users scroll to the bottom of the list, they don't have to go all the way back to the top to see the categories. So the behaviour of the SliverPersistentHeader is ok from this perspective. The problem is that it gets covered by the SliverAppBar when scrolling up, so it is not entirely visible to the user and it looks weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(new MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }

    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Home(),
        );
      }
    }


// I had to change this class to a StatefulWidget to be able to listen to the scroll event
    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return _HomeState();
      }
    }

    class _HomeState extends State<Home>  {
// Here I declared the ScrollController for the CustomScrollView
      ScrollController _controller;

// And here is a boolean to check when the user scrolls up or down the view
      bool sliverPersistentHeader = false;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
// The ScrollController is initialized in the initState and listens for when the user starts scrolling up and changes the boolean value accordingly
        _controller = ScrollController();
        _controller.addListener(() {
          if (_controller.position.userScrollDirection == ScrollDirection.reverse) {
            setState(() {
              sliverPersistentHeader = false;
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              sliverPersistentHeader = true;
            });
          }
        });
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        _controller.dispose();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: CustomScrollView(
            controller: _controller,
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                floating: true,
                pinned: true,
                expandedHeight: 200.0,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text('App Title'),
                ),
              ),
              SliverPersistentHeader(
// The SliverPersisitentHeader checks the boolean value and either pins or unpins the the Header
                pinned: sliverPersistentHeader ? true : false,
                delegate: CustomSliver(
                  expandedHeight: 150.0,
                ),
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (_, index) => Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50.0,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                title: Text('Tab1'),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                title: Text('Tab2'),
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Tab3'))
            ],
            currentIndex: 0,
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class CustomSliver extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
      final double expandedHeight;

      CustomSliver({@required this.expandedHeight});

      @override
      Widget build(
          BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
        return Scrollbar(
          child: Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 15.0, 0, 5.0),
              child: ListView.separated(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.16),
                                offset: Offset(0, 3.0),
                                blurRadius: 6.0),
                          ]),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.navigation),
                          Text(
                            'Category',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return SizedBox(width: 5.0);
                },
              )),
        );
      }

      @override
      double get maxExtent => expandedHeight;

      @override
      double get minExtent => 150.0;

      @override
      bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
        return true;
      }
    }
```

The only thing I didn't do was to animate the SliverPersistentHeader into view, hopefully, you can achieve this yourself. I'm sure there are other ways to achieve this, but this solution should work for you.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the help! The comments were really helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is still looking for a solution. You can try to implement this using a NestedScrollView and SliverOverlapAbsorber.

The following code will demonstrate this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomeState();
  }
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        floatHeaderSlivers: true,
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, isScrolled) => [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 200.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text('App Title'),
            ),
          ),
          SliverOverlapAbsorber(
            handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
            sliver: SliverPersistentHeader(
              floating: true,
              delegate: CustomSliver(
                expandedHeight: 150.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) => Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 50.0,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Tab1'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Tab2'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Tab3'))
        ],
        currentIndex: 0,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomSliver extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final double expandedHeight;

  CustomSliver({required this.expandedHeight});

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Scrollbar(
      child: Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 15.0, 0, 5.0),
          child: ListView.separated(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.16),
                            offset: Offset(0, 3.0),
                            blurRadius: 6.0),
                      ]),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.navigation),
                      Text(
                        'Category',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return SizedBox(width: 5.0);
            },
          )),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => expandedHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 150.0;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

- Notice the floatHeaderSlivers: true. On the NestedScrollView widget.
- Notice the SliverOverlapAbsorber

Some resources to help

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62194#issuecomment-664625589
- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html
- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverOverlapAbsorber-class.html